# Why Does CLion Hang on "Building..." Indefinitely On FreeBSD?

Tags: c++, freebsd, clion

I'm not sure what the cause of this is, I'm using the Linux version of CLion on FreeBSD, everything appears to work normally except when I go to build.  I made a simple CMake project from a template, hit the Run button after selecting the Run/Debug Configuration and it just spins saying "Building..." - but it actually builds.  In addition it outputs the command:

```
/usr/local/share/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/cory/projects/test/cmake-build-debug --target test -- -j 12
```

Which works perfectly from a shell window, returns immediately and produces the "test" binary which itself returns:

```
Hello, World!
```

When executed.  Does anyone know of a way to fix this so that CLion will detect that it did actually build and proceed to debug (or at least unblock the build button and execute) the binary?

Comment: Did you set run.processes.with.pty=false in idea.properties? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206525024-How-to-start-CLion-on-FreeBSD-

Comment: @arved Thanks, I completely missed that in my search, will have to check it out when I get home today.

Comment: @arved If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it, it worked.  I need to start reading manuals more often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `run.processes.with.pty=false` in `idea.properties`

For details:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206525024-How-to-start-CLion-on-FreeBSD-